# Wordpres Cron Jobs - Changing post meta after set time

Tags: wordpress, cron, hook, action, update-post-meta

I'm having trouble getting a cron job working in wordpress.

Setup:
I have a custom post type ('jobs') that have a couple of meta fields:
'featured' (bool) set to true if it is featured and
'feature-expiry' (DateTime) which is the time that the feature expires.

Goal:
Once the feature-expiry time has passed, update the post meta and change 'featured' to false

I'm kindof new to php and I can't seem to get it to work. The cron job fires fine but the posts aren't being updated, what am I doing wrong?

```
/*           jj cron jobs              */

function jj_feaurecheck_cron_function( ) {

  global $post;

  $args = array( 
    'post_type'       => 'jobs',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
  );

  $listings = get_posts( $args );
    foreach($listings as $post) : setup_postdata($post);

    $today = date( 'Ymd' );
    $expire = get_field( 'feature-expiry', false, false );
    $status = get_field( 'featured' );
        if ( $expire < $today ) :
            $status = 'false';
            update_field( 'featured', $status );
        endif;  
    endforeach;

}
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'jj_feaurecheck_cron' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( date( 'Ymd' ), 'daily', 'jj_feaurecheck_cron' );
}
add_action( 'jj_feaurecheck_cron', 'jj_feaurecheck_cron_function' );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! `get_field` is used for Advanced Custom Fields. Are you using ACF?

Comment: ty! =] ohh no i'm using Crocoblock JetEngine to create the post meta

Comment: Yeah, you should be using [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) to get the post meta fields.

Comment: Brilliant thank you I'll try that

Comment: Okay I updated it to use `get_post_meta()` and `update_post_meta()`, I also added a line to get the post ID. Still no go.. thoughts?

Comment: `get_post_meta($post_id, 'feature-expiry', false );`, change the `false` to `true` - you only want the single value. Also, instead of using `get_the_ID()`, simply use the `post` object's ID property. `$post->ID`

Comment: as in `$status = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured' );`?

Comment: OMIGOSH it worked!! thank you good sir! I will try to pay it forward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[---- Fix ----]

`get_field()` and `update_field()` are for use with Advanced Custom Fields, which my project isn't using. swtiched to `get_post_meta()` and `update_post_meta()`.

`if ( $expire < $today )` for some reason was affecting posts set to expire in the future so I switched them to unix time and that did the trick.

```
/*           jj cron jobs              */

function jj_feaurecheck_cron_function( ) {

  global $post;

  $args = array( 
    'post_type'       => 'jobs',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
  );

  $listings = get_posts( $args );
    foreach($listings as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
    
    $today = date( 'Ymd' );
    $expire = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'feature-expiry', true );
    $status = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured' );
    
      //get current date
      $today = new DateTime();

      //convert expire into a date obj
      $expire_date = new DateTime($expire);

      //convert dates to seconds for easier comparison
      $expire_secs = $expire_date->format('U');
      $today_secs  = $today->format('U');
    
      if ( $expire_secs < $today_secs ) :
          $status = 'false';
          //featured set to false
          update_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured', $status ); 
          //feature-expiry set back to empty
          update_post_meta($post->ID, 'feature-expiry', '' );
      endif;  
    endforeach;

}
add_action( 'jj_feaurecheck_cron', 'jj_feaurecheck_cron_function' );
```

Thank you disinfor and Steven for your guidance, I can't tell you how much I appreciate it! =]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this, I cannot test it so hopefully there are no errors but this is the general format i use to do what you are trying.

```
/**
 * jj cron jobs
 */
function jj_feaurecheck_cron_function( ) {

  $args = array(
    'post_type'       => 'jobs',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
  );

  $query = new WP_Query($args);

  if($query->have_posts()) {

    while($query->have_posts()) {

      the_post();

      //get the post id
      $post_id = get_the_ID();

      //get fields attached to post using ACF
      $expire = get_field( 'feature-expiry', $post_id, false );
      $status = get_field( 'featured', $post_id );

      //if not using ACF
      $expire = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'feature-expiry', true );
      $status = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'featured', true );

      //get current date
      $today = new DateTime();

      //convert expire into a date obj
      $expire_date = new DateTime($expire);

      //convert dates to seconds for easier comparison
      $expire_secs = $expire_date->format('U');
      $today_secs  = $today->format('U');

      //do the comparison
      if( $expire_secs < $today_secs ) {

          //update the field for that post ACF
          $status = 'false';
          update_field( 'featured', $status, $post_id );

          //non ACF
          update_post_meta($post_id, 'featured', $status);
      } 
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'jj_feaurecheck_cron', 'jj_feaurecheck_cron_function' );
```

Comment: This doesn't work because `get_field()` is an Advanced Custom Fields function. The original code _should_ work when using the correct function to get the meta fields.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will try this aswell with `get_post_meta()`
edit- oh you updated it, thank you trying now

Comment: I should be using `update_post_meta()` if i'm not using ACF, correct?

Comment: yeah my bad I will edit